# Runtime Exec in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, exec

Is it possible to use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe");
```

in gwt?  When I compile it, I get

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission <<ALL FILES>> execute)
```

Any workarounds / ideas?

Comment: See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/RefJreEmulation.html for a list of classes and methods that you *can* use inside of GWT code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't.

GWT is eventually compiled to Javascript. Javascript cannot run arbitrary apps on your (local) machine

Comment: Good point ... I think I have officially given up trying to tie in a compiled Matlab script into GWT =/

Comment: You can do that on the server side and have the client code make a call to return the results. See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideServerCommunication.html for details.