# how to give execute permission for google AppEngineFile?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have created a google appengine file but When I try to execute it (Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)) its giving me the below error

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "<<ALL FILES>>" "execute")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:383)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkExec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at in.javadomain.GoogleBlobServlet.runProcess(GoogleBlobServlet.java:113)
at in.javadomain.GoogleBlobServlet.Mymain(GoogleBlobServlet.java:149)
at in.javadomain.GoogleBlobServlet.doGet(GoogleBlobServlet.java:37)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:368)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:351)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:485)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

and also I have tried giving filepermission in the java class itself like below,

```
FilePermission p = new FilePermission("<<ALL FILES>>", "execute");
            FilePermission p1 = new FilePermission("/blobstore/"+myFile+"", "execute");
            FilePermission p2 = new FilePermission("/blobstore/*", "execute");
            java.lang.RuntimePermission rp = new RuntimePermission("<<ALL FILES>>");
            java.lang.RuntimePermission rp1 = new RuntimePermission("/blobstore/-");
            java.lang.RuntimePermission rp2 = new RuntimePermission("/blobstore/*");
            java.security.AllPermission ap = new AllPermission();
```

I checked the file permission like below and its having executable permission,

```
[java] if(p1.implies(new FilePermission("/blobstore/"+myFile+"", "execute"))) {
                     System.out.println("hey i have execute permission");
                  }
                else{
                    System.out.println("so sad i am not having");
                } [/java]
```

But still I am getting the above mentioned error. Please provide me possible solutions.

Comment: did you check, if is it the file permission of your file/foler system? or where you have kept the files?

Comment: @NiteshVerma file path is/blobstore/writable:YO-jxNnF2ZvrK5Wz3HtUuA

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166779/running-exe-on-server-side  - you can't execute things, the code you are trying to execute must be moved into your application.

Comment: @tim hoffman do you have any sample code on how to move that file to our application ?

Comment: Nope, I don't do java ;-)